# Is there a way to see how JavaScript creates Objects?

Tags: javascript

I am working with is code:

```
var obj1 = new Object('some text'),
    obj2 = new Object(32);

console.log(obj1 instanceof String);  // true
console.log(typeof obj1); //object
console.log(obj2 instanceof Number); // true
console.log(typeof obj2); // object
```

I am guessing that the `Object` function has a constructor that determines whether the newly created object is an instance of `String` or `Number`

I am really interested to see how it is done. Is it possible to see the Object function itself? Similarly how we - for example - can open up the jQuery library and see how it implements Ajax.

Comment: The implementation may differ across browsers. It may be implemented in JavaScript. Either way, your best bet is to look up the source code of popular browsers. Most browsers are open source.

Comment: all cores follow the spec, so in a way, yes you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to see the Object function itself? Similarly how we can open up the jQuery library

No, it's not that easy. The `Object` function is a native function, built into the JavaScript environment, and is not implemented as an open-source JavaScript library.

To see what the function does internally, there are basically two ways:

- Look at the spec. In the case of `Object`, you're lucky and [it is quite easy to read](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-value) (ignore the first two steps and jump to [`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject))
- Look at the implementation of an open-source engine. If you're lucky, the native function is defined in a JavaScript file using other native primitives. In that case, it often matches the spec rather closely. If you're not so lucky, it is implemented in the native language of the engine.